# avro AVSC (json) file array or schema re-use

Tags: avro

This is related to a question that's been asked myriad times but I can't find a clear answer.

In AVSC (json) syntax for defining avro schemas, there is no 'import' capability. So it seems there's no clear way to define a schema and reference it elsewhere. (I recognize AVDL supports `import` but the java parser doesn't yet allow for `uuid` types, though that is patched and will be fixed in 1.11)

I see a lot of answers to 'how to re-use schemas' that rely on using the `avro maven plugin` to define 'includes' which is great if you're using java, but I'm working in a polyglot environment.

I have toyed around with this syntax in an AVSC file which is working for me in maven/java but seems entirely undocumented:

```json
[
  // ^ note: starts with a top-level array
  {
    // schema 1

    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.mycompany",
    "name": "Money",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "amount",
        "type": {
          "type": "bytes",
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "scale": 2,
          "precision": 19
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "currency",
        "type": "string",
        "doc": "3-character ISO 4217 currency code"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // schema 2, references schema 1
    
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.mycompany.budgeting"
    "name": "BudgetsModified",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "logicalType": "uuid"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "amount",
        // re-use
        "type": "com.mycompany.Money"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but is this *actually* supported or just a quirk of the maven avro plugin?

The problems I'm specifically looking to address:

- must support java, python, and (ideally) typescript (so a maven-only solution is no good)
- must support schema referencing/re-use -- I don't want to redefine a custom tuple like `Money` (a decimal with a currency) in every schema that requires it
- must interoperate with Confluent Schema Registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is this actually supported or just a quirk of the maven avro plugin?

This is a completely valid way of combining/referencing schemas. In fact, in the python `fastavro` library [there is a `load_schema` API](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro/blob/4777a11dbc718b05ca8a244e7a0ecc080f0d50d6/fastavro/_schema_py.py#L413-L499) that originally would do basically just that; it would load all the schemas into a list (Avro Union) because that was a correct and easy way to solve the problem.

As for `must interoperate with Confluent Schema Registry`, I don't know how the schema registry works and if it supports this type of unioned schema, but hopefully it should because the schema is valid.

Comment: Thanks! It *seems* valid to me as well, but I was hoping to see any documentation indicating such. I'm always nervous to rely on things that 'happen to work now' but aren't to any spec.

Comment: The specification says that a schema can be defined as an array of embedded schemas so I would say this is already covered in the specification: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schemas